# Denseness of finite rank operators in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. As noted in the answers to a question on

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535645/weak-operator-topology-and-finite-rank-operators

the finite rank operators lie dense in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ with respect to the strong operator topology (SOT-topology). I would like to know under which assumptions on the Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ one can approximate an arbitrary $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ in the SOT-topology by a *norm-bounded sequence* of finite rank operators.

It seems to me that the proof of denseness of the finite rank operators cited above does not yield approximation by norm-bounded sequences. I can obtain the required approximation under the assumption that $X$ is separable and that either $X$ or $Y$ has the bounded approximation property. However, these assumptions yield a stronger statement, namely that one can approximate a general $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ by a norm-bounded sequence of finite-rank operators in the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $X$. This clearly implies SOT-convergence, but it might be a strictly stronger statement than what I am looking for.

Does anyone know whether one can approximate an arbitrary $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ by a norm-bounded sequence of finite-rank operators in the SOT-topology for more general Banach spaces than those mentioned above?

Comment: Is it important that you want a sequence, or will a net do?

Comment: If you can approximate at all, $\|T_n\|\le C$ is automatic from the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Sequences will obviously ($T=I$) not suffice on non-separable spaces.

Comment: For bounded nets, strong convergence is the same as uniform convergence on compact sets.

Comment: @YemonChoi: No, sequences are vital in this case, as I need them for an application of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Good point, so the question becomes under which assumptions the finite rank operators are sequentially dense in B(X,Y).

Comment: @BillJohnson: In that case I think my question might have a clear answer, for the following reason. Suppose X is such that, for each Banach space Y, every $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is the limit of a norm-bounded sequence of finite rank operators. As you said, $T$ is then the limit of this sequence in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. This almost seems to imply that X has BAP. Indeed, if one would know that there is a constant $\lambda$ such that the norms of the sequence elements are bounded by $\lambda$ times the norm of T, then X would have BAP.

Comment: And perhaps the existence of such a $\lambda$ follows automatically, for otherwise one might be able to construct a $T\in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ which is not the limit of a norm-bounded sequence of finite rank operators. I'll think about all of this some more, thank you for the comments!